# trac bloodhound internals/ url dispatcher

Tags: trac, apache-bloodhound

I want to learn Trac and Bloodhound source code.  I have a background in web programming and some frameworks especially Django.  But Trac and Bloodhound are quite different from the traditional web applications build with frameworks.

How does the URL dispatcher work for these projects? 
How does source code browser work?

Comment: Some documentation on the request handling can be found [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/RequestHandling). I can't give you a detailed answer, but in case you aren't aware, some documentation can be found on the [TracDev](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django you have the URL dispatcher, which matches requests to certain patterns and then passes a HttpRequest as the first argument to the associated view function(see [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)).

In Trac you have a number of interfaces which match requests in a similar way. The simplest example is the IRequestHandler which has two methods, [match_request()](http://www.edgewall.org/docs/trac-trunk/html/api/trac_web_api.html#trac.web.api.IRequestHandler.match_request) and [process_request()](http://www.edgewall.org/docs/trac-trunk/html/api/trac_web_api.html#trac.web.api.IRequestHandler.process_request). You can think of the the match_request() as the URL pattern matching in Django, and the process_request() as the subsequent view which is invoked if the associated match_request() returns True.

For an example of this from the Trac sourcecode, see how trac matches requests to view tickets inside [trac/ticket/web_ui.py](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/ticket/web_ui.py#L174)

```
# IRequestHandler methods

def match_request(self, req):
    if req.path_info == "/newticket":
        return True
    match = re.match(r'/ticket/([0-9]+)$', req.path_info)
    if match:
        req.args['id'] = match.group(1)
        return True

def process_request(self, req):
    if 'id' in req.args:
        if req.path_info == '/newticket':
            raise TracError(_("id can't be set for a new ticket request."))
        return self._process_ticket_request(req)

    return self._process_newticket_request(req)
```

So if you wanted to write a plugin which matches web requests, you would have to implement an extension point for the IRequestHandler interface. The convention is to put web related stuff in a web_ui.py file, which would have to define a new Component. I recommend you read [this Trac dev page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.api.IRequestHandler) for another example.

In the diagram RjOllos linked to, you can actually see that there are a number of interface at work for each request. For example you can change the handler inside a pre_process_request() or add data after a initial match_request() with a post_process_request(). These are methods from the [IRequestFilter inteface](http://www.edgewall.org/docs/trac-trunk/html/api/trac_web_api.html#trac.web.api.IRequestFilter).

For the full list of interfaces which can be invoked when handing web requests, see [trac.web.api](http://www.edgewall.org/docs/trac-trunk/html/api/trac_web_api.html#module-trac.web.api).

One final subtlety to note, is that in Django you have a [request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object, but in Trac you have a [req](http://www.edgewall.org/docs/trac-trunk/html/api/trac_web_api.html#trac.web.api.Request) object. They contain similar method and attributes, describing the meta-data around each request.

Comment: Thanks... That's what im looking for